# Is there a way to send message with MQSTR format using JmsSendingMessageHandler

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-jms

I am using `JmsSendingMessageHandler` to send JMS message

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "queueChannel" )
public MessageHandler sendMessageOnTopic() {

    JmsSendingMessageHandler messageHandler = new JmsSendingMessageHandler(jmsTemplate);
    messageHandler.setDestinationExpression(new FunctionExpression<Message<?>>(message -> message.getHeaders().get("destination")));
    return messageHandler;

}
```

by default messages goes to MQ with format `MQHRF2`. problem with that is mainframe only understands `MQSTR` format,

Is there a way I can do it with some configuration or adding any headers (I tried adding `JMS_IBM_Format` to `MQSTR` as message header but did not work) ?

I am able to achieve the same if I use jmsTemplate directly like below

```
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("queue:///" + message.getHeaders().get("destination") + "?targetClient=1", message.getPayload());
```

I was wondering if I can achieve the same results with `JmsSendingMessageHandler` ?

Comment: How about this then: `messageHandler.setDestinationExpression(new FunctionExpression<Message<?>>(message -> "queue:///" + message.getHeaders().get("destination") + "?targetClient=1"))` ?

Comment: it worked, earlier I interpreted `queue:///` as `queue://` because of the `double quotes` present in the string and was passing the entire expression as `queue://QUEUE_NAME?targetClient=1` instead of passing it as `queue:///QUEUE_NAME?targetClient=1` through yml directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Artem mentioned in the comments, this can be done as

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "queueChannel" )
public MessageHandler sendMessageOnTopic() {

    JmsSendingMessageHandler messageHandler = new JmsSendingMessageHandler(jmsTemplate);
    messageHandler.setDestinationExpression(new FunctionExpression<Message<?>>(message -> "queue:///" + message.getHeaders().get("destination") + "?targetClient=1"));
    return messageHandler;

}
```

or even if we pass the destination as `queue:///QUEUE_NAME?targetClient=1` directly from yml.